# I can't boot my nexus 4 after trying to install custom rom, please help

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, backup, custom-roms

I am pretty new to all this stuff and i tried to install android L alpha preview on my nexus 4. I rooted my phone and downloaded the .zip file and then followed the instructions on the internet site. I reset all my data and wiped dalvik cache but forgot, that i had .zip file under my downloads. I couldn't install it, because i deleted it and i deleted everything else on my phone too. So now my phone won't boot and I don't now what to do. I also can't transfer my files from computer to phone. Please help, I'm really desperate.

(sorry for my English, not a native speaker)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, the solution is pretty easy.

Download Wugrfesh toolkit from here:
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95747613655047107

Once you open the program, press "Flash stock + unroot" on the right side. Just follow the instructions and you'll do fine.

Good luck :)